# 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode()' error with springweb 6.0.x and oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-oauth2.1

Recently we migrated from spring boot 2.x to 3.x when i tried hit a restapi through restclinet i am getting exception.
After migrating we have springweb 6.x and oauth2 2.4 as our dependencies.
I went through the code base of both dependencies I find out that
In springweb 6.x ClientHttpResponse returning HttpStatusCode
[image]

In Springweb 5.3.x ClientHttpResponse returning HttpStatus
[image]

But in oauth2 handler it is expecting HttpStatus, but spring web 6 returning HttpStatusCode
[image]

How can we fix this incompatible can some help with solution to get rid of this error.

5.3.x code : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpResponse.java
6.x code : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6.0.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpResponse.java

Oauth2 code : https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/blob/main/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/http/OAuth2ErrorHandler.java

Answer (score 0):

`spring-security-oauth` is just not compatible with Spring Security 6 / Boot 3 and [it won't be](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth):

> spring-security-oauth is no longer actively maintained by VMware, Inc.

> This project has been replaced by the OAuth2 support provided by [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) (client and resource server) and [Spring Authorization Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server).

If you're looking for something simpler than `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, you can have a look at [this starter I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc).

If you're looking at something requiring less code than `spring-authorization-server`, then have a look at products like Keycloak or cloud offers like Auth0, Amazon Cognito, Okta, ...